# How do I properly define media types for multiple stylesheets?

Tags: css, media

I've got a web page that I know is being viewed in various browsers, with mobile devices, etc. I just want to add a printable view.

The current stylesheet link looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somefile.css" media="all" />
```

What I want is to do the equivilent of "if print, use this new stylesheet; else use the original one."

To do that, can I simply add a print stylesheet, like this?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="somefile.css" media="print" />
```

In other words, does it make sense to have both "all" to catch any device type I may not be thinking of, and "print" for that specific media?

Answer (score 2):

From [a W3 schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp):

```
@media screen {
    p.test {font-family:verdana,sans-serif;font-size:14px;}
}
@media print {
    p.test {font-family:times,serif;font-size:10px;}
}
@media screen,print {
    p.test {font-weight:bold;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) clearly says that the `all` media type means the stylesheet is suitable to *all* media types.

If this is correct, you are fine to use it.

However, chances are this is not quite the case (is it really suitable for `speech`?), so you should set the main stylesheet to `screen`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="screen.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="print.css" media="print" />
```

You can also define media type *within* a single css file, to signify which rules should be used with which media type using `@media` at-rules.